# how to remove gaps between navigation links

Tags: html, css

I am trying to bridge the gap between navigation menus so that the red background is completely covered.

```
<nav>
    <a class="current_page" href="index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home </a>
    <a href="blog.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Blog</a>
    <a href="photography.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> Photos </a>
    <a href="videos.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span> videos</a>
    <a href="feedback.php"> Feedback </a>
    <a href="about.php"> About </a>
</nav>
```

and my css is:-

```
nav{
    background-color:red;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

a{
  margin:0px;
  padding:5px;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#6a97d5;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z4gLqp61/3/

Comment: @MohammadUsman Yep, it is a duplicate. [Removing `white-space` between `a` works.](https://jsfiddle.net/z4gLqp61/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Change Margin CSS like:

```
 a{
    margin:0px -5px;
    padding:5px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#6a97d5;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you just need to add

```
a { margin-right:-4px; }
```

because whenever you write `display:inline-block` it takes an additional `margin-right:4px`

so, you need to remove it by adding CSS code.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.